# How can I write a conditional :each in ruby more succinctly?

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure how to write this code more cleanly in ruby? The only thing that differs is the iterator.

```
  if items.respond_to?(:find_each)
    items.find_each do |item|
      output_item(csv, item)
    end
  else
    items.each do |item|
      output_item(csv, item)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where does `items` come from and why does it respond to different methods?

Comment: I don't know the OP's use case, but if `items` were an ActiveRecord::Relation it would respond to `find_each`. If it were an Array it would not. Perhaps the OP has some cases for optimization where the search result is converted to an Array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) to call method dynamically:

```
method = items.respond_to?(:find_each) ? :find_each : :each
items.send(method) do |item|
  output_item(csv, item)
end
```

Comment: Eh, you beat me to it... :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could do:

```
method = items.respond_to?(:find_each) ? :find_each : :each
items.send(method) { |item| output_item(csv, item) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to make the intent for this branch a bit clearer:

```
iterator = items.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation) ? :find_each : :each
items.send(iterator) { |item| output_item(csv, item) }
```

Which iterator to pick is an implementation detail which might make my business logic harder to understand. Let's extract iteration logic into a separate method. The benefit of this extraction is debatable if the total business logic is a one liner. It will add more clarity if the original method is longer.

```
def iterate(relation_or_array, *args, &block)
  iterator = relation_or_array.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation) ? :find_each : :each
  relation_or_array.send(iterator, *args, &block)
end

# main logic
iterate(items) { |item| output_item(csv, item) }
```

Now that we're free of the original method, I'd expand the ternary `if` to improve readability.

```
def iterate(relation_or_array, *args, &block)
  if relation_or_array.is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation
    relation_or_array.find_each(*args, &block)
  else 
    relation_or_array.each(*args, &block)
  end
end

# main logic
iterate(items) { |item| output_item(csv, item) }
```